# Gtk2Hs : Missing functions when migrating from Gtk2 to Gtk3

Tags: haskell, gtk3, gtk2hs

I wrote a Haskell program with `Gtk2Hs` dealing with `Gtk2`. But when I tried to build my program with `Gtk3`, GHC complains about missing functions which doesn't exist anymore :

```
• Variable not in scope:
    widgetGetSize :: GtkGL.GLDrawingArea -> IO (Integer, Integer)

• Variable not in scope:
    renderWithDrawable :: t1 -> Render () -> IO ()
```

**Do you know if there are functions in `Gtk3` which could replace these functions ?**

**Is there another way in Gtk3 to get the size of a widget ?**

---

Note : I still can build my program with Gtk2 but I woulk like to anticipate a full migration to Gtk3

Answer (score 0):

**GtkGLArea** — A widget for custom drawing with OpenGL

API: ( [C](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGLArea.html) ) ( [Vala](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.GLArea.html) )

> GtkGLArea is a widget that allows drawing with OpenGL.
>
> GtkGLArea sets up its own GdkGLContext for the window it creates, and
>   creates a custom GL framebuffer that the widget will do GL rendering
>   onto. It also ensures that this framebuffer is the default GL
>   rendering target when rendering.
>
> In order to draw, you have to connect to the “render” signal, or
>   subclass GtkGLArea and override the GtkGLAreaClass.render() virtual
>   function.
>
> The GtkGLArea widget ensures that the GdkGLContext is associated with
>   the widget's drawing area, and it is kept updated when the size and
>   position of the drawing area changes.

**GtkWidget Size**

To get the widget size, use the GtkAllocation getters. Notice that GtkWidget has request size methods but the allocated size may differ.

- Width: ( [C](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-allocated-width) ) ( [Vala](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.get_allocated_width.html) )
- Height: ( [C](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-allocated-height) ) ( [Vala](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.get_allocated_height.html) )
- GtkAllocation: ( [C](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-allocation) ) ( [Vala](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.get_allocated_size.html) )